# When does a markov chain become independent of initial state

Tags: markov-chains

IF we are given a markov chain probability matrix represented by

$$P = \left(\begin{matrix} a&&b&&c\\d&&e&&f\\g&&h&&i\end{matrix}\right)$$

and $a+b+c=d+e+f=g+h+i=1$ with an initial state $(x, y, z)$

Is there a way to know whether after how many  iterations the matrix becomes independent of initial state? I know that in excel sheet, we can continue multiplying P a number of times until we get some thing like say

$$P=\left(\begin{matrix} a&&b&&c\\a&&b&&c\\a&&b&&c\end{matrix}\right)$$

but is it possible to find n at which it achieves this state without using an excel sheet ?

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of eigenvalues of a matrix?

Comment: Usually, never. This is a limit case. If, for instance, $P$ has determinant $\neq0$, no power $P^n$ of $P$ may have determinant $0$.

Comment: Thank you. Does it mean that if determinant of a matrix is 0, then it is possible that for some value of n we will achieve that state? In such cases, is it possible to find n without actually multiply P n times?

Comment: It never happens that $P\ne P^\infty$ but $P^n=P^\infty$ for some finite $n$.